# Can I travel to Romania on a Schengen Visa?

Tags: schengen, romania, south-african-citizens

I am a South African with a Schengen Visa and visiting Poland as my country of entry. Can I then travel on to Romania. I can't clearly find out if Romania is Schengen or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter Romania on a Schengen visa IF it is a multiple entry Schengen visa.

From the [Romanian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040)

> Categories of third-state nationals also exempt from the requirement
>   to be in possession of a Romanian short-stay visa are:
>
> The holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, national
>   visas or residence permits issued by Schengen Member States.